# Run some functionality before all test suites in minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

This is my code:

```
class LoginTest < MiniTest::Test
  def before_all
    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = DRIVER_PATH
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
  end

  def test_one
  end

  def test_two
  end
end
```

I want to call the driver method before all test suites.

Is there a way to run some code once before all suites?

Comment: I googled and tried many things but not get success. My objective is that i want to call driver method before all test suite files for once.

Comment: That article describes your exact use case in the *"Setting Up Before Running the Suite"* section at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late, and you probably already have find your answer,

but here is the solution

```rb
class LoginTest < MiniTest::Test
  setup do 
    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = DRIVER_PATH
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
  end

  def test_one
  end

  def test_two
  end
end
```

the code present in the function `setup` will be run before each test